# Distribute content to particular Android Webview?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-webview

I have an issue for my e-Book app that is I intend to make e-Book page by Webview, but the problem here is paging when its content is too long, I dont want user vertical scroll, uhmm... I mean the content will be cut and hold into a number of Webview base on the height of screen. Can we distibute continuously the content to particular Webview.

Thank for your reading

Comment: get the screensize and set content accordingly?

Comment: for example my contain is 500 lines with certain text size, and each web view can display 100 lines to fit the screen, so I have to share it continiously with 5 Web views. Can we do that ?

Comment: why are you using 5 webviews? I mean more than one?

Comment: I dont want user verticaly scroll, I put 5 webviews into viewpager maybe

Comment: If you have raw text of those 500 lines. you can do it programatically to check if one webview is full or not. is it html you want to display in the webview?